# Alternative for MSWC.AdRotator

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, adrotator

I have used `MSWC.AdRotator` in one of my web site created in ASP.

But as I have moved my application from `IIS 6` to `IIS 7`,  that control is not working.

But I want that `AdRotator` in my application.

So what would be the prefered Alternative for `AdRotator`

Comment: You could store your ads in a database and randonly retrieve a row and show the ad. Or for a more simple solution just put your ads in an include file and generate a random number to select an ad. If you need help with doing this post your current code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replaced this component with the JQuery Rotator.